# Client-side SSL theoretical question

Tags: authentication, ssl, certificate, client-side

I work at company X and we want to engage in a B2B transaction with company Y.  In doing so, Y is requiring client side authentication; they already provide server-side authentication - so this would be a mutual SSL transaction.

My understanding is that I simply need to provide my CA-signed cert as part of my client side HTTPS communication.  In doing so, asymmetric cryptographic guarantees (i.e., public/private key technology) ensures that I am who I claim I am - in effect, it is not possible to impersonate me.  (the root CA has ensured I am who I am, that is why they signed my cert, and it's possible to prove that I didn't "manufacture" the certificate).

Here's my question: is this all I need to provide company Y?

Alternatively, do I have to provide them with *another* key in advance, so that they can ensure I am not a rogue who happens to have "gotten a hold" of a root-signed certificate for me (company X)?  It would seem that if one has to provide this extra key to all parties he wishes to engage with on the client side, it would seem to make client-side SSL not as scalable as server-side SSL.  My guess is that it's not possible for one to "get a hold" of a client side cert; that the actual transmission of the client side cert is further encoded by some state of the transaction (which is not reverse-engineerable, feasibly).

Does this make sense and am I right or am I wrong?  If I'm wrong, does Y in effect need to get an "extra" pre-communication key from every party that connects to it? (which they want to verify)?

Thanks.

===

Thanks for the responses below, at least the first two have been helpful so far (others may arrive later).

Let me talk in a bit more detail about my technical concern.

Suppose company Y attempts to "re-use" my client side cert to impersonate me in another client-side transaction with another company (say "Z").  Is this even possible?  I am thinking - again, perhaps poorly stated - that some part of the *transmission of the client side certificate* prevents the entire key from being compromised, i.e., that is not technically feasible to "re-use" a client certificate received because you could not (feasibly) reverse engineer the communication which communicate the client cert.

If this is not the case, couldn't Y re-use the cert, impersonating X when communicating (client-side) to Z?

ps: I realize that security is never 100%, just trying to understand what is technically feasible here and what is not.

Thanks very much!

===

Further technical details, I appreciate any additional input very much - this has been very quite helpful.

From a layman's point of view, my concern is that when a client sends his client cert, what is he sending?  Well, he has to encrypt that cert using his private key.  He sends the ciphertext with the public key, and then a receiving party can use that public key to decrypt the private-key-encoded payload, right?  That makes sense, but then I wonder -- what prevents someone from hearing that communication and simply re-using the private key encoded payload in a replay attack.  Just replay the exact ones and zeroes sent.

Here's what I believe prevents that -- it can be found in the TLS RFC, in multiple places, but for example in F.1.1:

```
F.1.1. Authentication and key exchange

   TLS supports three authentication modes: authentication of both
   parties, server authentication with an unauthenticated client, and
   total anonymity. Whenever the server is authenticated, the channel is
   secure against man-in-the-middle attacks, but completely anonymous
   sessions are inherently vulnerable to such attacks.  Anonymous
   servers cannot authenticate clients. If the server is authenticated,
   its certificate message must provide a valid certificate chain
   leading to an acceptable certificate authority.  Similarly,
   authenticated clients must supply an acceptable certificate to the
   server. Each party is responsible for verifying that the other's
   certificate is valid and has not expired or been revoked.

   The general goal of the key exchange process is to create a
   pre_master_secret known to the communicating parties and not to
   attackers. The pre_master_secret will be used to generate the
   master_secret (see Section 8.1). The master_secret is required to
   generate the certificate verify and finished messages, encryption
   keys, and MAC secrets (see Sections 7.4.8, 7.4.9 and 6.3). By sending
   a correct finished message, parties thus prove that they know the
   correct pre_master_secret.
```

I believe it's the randomization associated with the session that prevents these replay attacks.

Sound right or am I confusing things further?

Comment: Almost right---there is randomization in each handshake that prevents replays. The client is authenticated by *digitally signing* some content that's unique to the session. See the update to my answer for a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client-side certificate (or more precisely its private key), is only as secure as your company's online and/or physical security let it be.

For extremely secure relations (which typically do not have the requirement of scaling much), it may be acceptable that the provider of the service requires an extra element in the protocol which allows them to identify your site (and more often than not, to identify *a particular computer* or *individual* within the company, which is something client certs do not fully do.)

This of course brings the question: what is warranty that this extra bit of authentication device will be more securely held by your company? (as compared to the client-site certificate itself).
 The standard response for this is that these extra bits of security elements are typically non-standards, possibly associated with physical devices, machine IDs and such, and are therefore less easily transportable (and the know-how about these is less common: hackers know what RSA files to look for, and what they look like, what do they know of the genesis and usage of the KBD-4.hex file ?)

Extra question: Can Y make use of my client-side certificate elsewhere?
No they [normally] cannot! The integrity of this certificate lies in your safe keeping of its private key (and, yes, a similar safekeeping from the certificate providers...).  Therefore, unless they are responsible for installing the said certificate, or unless their software on your client (if any) somehow "hacks" into certificate-related storage / files / system dlls, they should not be able to reuse the certificate.  That is they cannot reuse the certificate any more easily (which is theoretically NP hard) than anyone that, say, would sniff the packets related to authentication as the client establishes a session with the Y site.

Extra questionS ;-) 
 - What is the nature of the client cert?
 - Man-in-the-middle concerns...

Before getting to these, let's **clear a few things up**...
The question seems to imply **TLS** ([Transport Layer Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)) which is indeed a good protocol for this purpose, but for sake of understanding, the keys (public and private) from the certs (server's and client's) could well be used with alternative protocols.  And also, TLS itself offers several different possible *encryption algorithms* for its support (one of the initial phases of a TLS session is for both parties to negotiate the set of algorithms they'll effectively use).
Also, what goes without saying... (also goes if you say it): **the respective private keys are NEVER transmitted in any fashion**, encoded or not. The confusion sometimes arise because after the authentication phase, the parties **exchange a key** (typically for a symmetric cipher) that is used in subsequent exchanges.  This key is typically randomly generated, and of totally different nature than the RSA keys whether public or private!

In a simplified fashion, the **client's certificate contains the following information**:
  - The Certificate Authority (CA aka issuer)
  - The "owner" of the certificate (aka Subject)
  - Validity date range
  - the PUBLIC key of the certificate
In more detail, the certificates are typically found in an [**X.509** wrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) (? envelope), which contains additional fields such as version number, algorithm used, certificate ID, a certificate signature (very important to ensure that the certificate received wasn't tempered with).  The X.509 also provide for optional attributes, and is also used for transmitting other types of certificate-related data (such as the CRL)

Therefore **the certificate's content allow the recipient to**:
 - ensure the certificate itself was not tempered with
 - ensure that the issuer of the certificate is one accepted by the recipient
 - ensure that the certificate is valid/current and not revoked
 - know the public key and its underlying size and algorithm

With regards to **man-in-the-middle concerns**, in particular the possibility of "re-playing" a possibly recorded packet exchange from a previous session.

The protocol uses *variable*, possibly random MACs (Message Authentication Codes) for that purpose. Essentially, during the negotiation phase, one of the parties (not sure which, may vary...) produces a random string of sorts and sends it to the other party.  This random value is then used, as-is (or, typically, with some extra processing by an algorithm known by both parties) as part of the messages sent.  It being encoded with the private key of teh sending party, if the the receiving party can decode it (with sender's public key) and recognize the (again variable) MAC, then it is proof that the sender is in possession of the private key of the certificate, and hence its identity is asserted.  Because the MACs vary each time, pre-recorded sessions are of no help (for this simple purpose).

Comment: very helpful, i added some more detail to my question (see original question), per your follow-up, can you possibly check it out?

Answer (score 4):

As long as you keep the private key safe (and the CA keeps their signing key safe), "company Y" doesn't need any other information to *authenticate* you. In other words, they can be sure that a request really came from the subject named in the certificate.

However, this doesn't mean that you are *authorized* to do anything. In practice, most systems that use client certificates have an "out of band" process where you provide the "subject" distinguished name that is specified in the client certificate, and the system assigns some privileges to that name.

In fact, because of some practical limitations, some systems actually associate the privileges with the certificate itself (using the issuer's name and the certificate serial number). This means that if you get a new certificate, you might have to re-enroll it, even if it has the same subject name.

A certificate only assures a relying party you have a certain name. That party needs some additional mechanism to determine what you are allowed to do.

---

Unlike authentication mechanisms based on "secret" (symmetric) keys—e.g., passwords—a server only needs public information for asymmetric authentication. A private signing key should *never* be disclosed; it's certainly not necessary for client authentication.

With symmetric, password-based authentication, the client and server get access to the same string of bytes—the secret key. With public-key cryptography, only the public key of a key pair is disclosed. The corresponding private key is never disclosed, and no practical method for figuring out the private key from the public key has been discovered.

As long as you keep your private key safe, the server at company Y cannot forge requests that appear to come from you.

---

Client authentication replay attacks are defeated by requiring the client to digitally sign a message that includes a number randomly generated by the server for each handshake (this is the "random" member of the "ServerHello" message). If the packet used to authenticate the client in a previous session were re-used, a server will be unable to verify the signature, and won't authenticate the replay attack.

[RFC 2246, Appendix F.1.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246#appendix-F.1.1.2) might be a more helpful reference—especially the third paragraph:

> When RSA is used for key exchange, clients are authenticated using
> the certificate verify message (see Section 7.4.8). The client signs
> a value derived from the master_secret and all preceding handshake
> messages. These handshake messages include the server certificate,
> which binds the signature to the server, and ServerHello.random,
> which binds the signature to the current handshake process.

Comment: very helpful, i added some more detail to my question (see original question), per your follow-up, can you possibly check it out?